# Should I use jQuery(this) in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For background, I have this PHP which outputs HTML `a:link` divs, each with a different `$linkname` and `$pageid`, and generates a script that has the same corresponding `$linkname` and `$pageid`'s for each link div:

```
$output = '<a class="sig_lightbox_link" id="' . $pageid . '">' . $linkname . '<span class="spinner"></span></a>';

        $output .= "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery(\"a.sig_lightbox_link#$pageid\").click(function() {
                        jQuery(\".spinner\").show();
                        sig_lightbox_fire(jQuery(this).attr(\"id\"));
                    });
                });
            </script>";
```

That works OK and outputs the HTML and jQuery i.e. below for each `$linkname` and `$pageid` i.e., `838`:

```
 <a class="lightbox_link" id="838">Link<span class="spinner" style="display: none;"></span></a>
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("a.lightbox_link#838").click(function() {
            jQuery(".spinner").show();
            sig_lightbox_fire(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });
// more links and scripts below
```

in style.css, `.spinner` is `display:none`.

The problem I'm seeing is that with a click on any one of the links on a page with many of these HTML and Javascript blocks, the spinner appears in all spans on the page, not just in the span with the a:link that was clicked.

I tried `jQuery(".spinner").closest().show();` with no luck.

Should I use (this) to target only the most immediate link and .spinner span?

Comment: ID attributes must start with a letter

Comment: You shouldn't generate a separate script tag for each link

Comment: I know the code is messy; it's inherited. So all I need is to change to #spinner?

Comment: Thanks! (this).find works great. I had tried just (this) with no luck. I'll also change to one Javascript for all the links. You should add all this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `jQuery(".spinner").show();` to `jQuery(this).find(".spinner").show();`. What you have currently will select all elements with the class spinner no matter where it is on the page.

While you are at it, change `jQuery("a.lightbox_link#838")` to `jQuery("a.lightbox_link")` and place this javascript AFTER all the links are generated, do not generate a separate script tag for each link. There is also no need to define this javascript in a PHP string at all.